# Sharing current view via ACTION_SEND without storing the image in android

Tags: java, android, share, android-permissions, android-sharing

I want to share the current view of the app using ACTION_SEND.

The method of converting the current view to bitmap and storing it in external storage for converting the bitmap to a parsable Uri needs permissions.

Snippet:

```
    public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
        View screenView = view.getRootView();
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }

    // View to BitMap
    Bitmap b  = getScreenShot(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));

    //BitMap to Parsable Uri (needs write permissions)
    String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,"title", null);
    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);

    //Share the image
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

This needs **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission, 
Is there a  way to perform the same without storing it in external storage (without permissions) on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, you can use `getExternalFilesDir()` to write the image to external storage and avoid the permission issue.

You can write the file to internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`), then share it using `FileProvider`. You need to use `FileProvider` or some `ContentProvider` going forward anyway, as [Android 7.0+ does not like the `file` scheme](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

If you want to avoid the disk I/O... you would have to compress the `Bitmap` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then write your own `ContentProvider` to serve from that `byte[]`. This is somewhat risky, in that if your process is terminated before the other app winds up trying to use the `Uri`, you are out of luck, as your bitmap is gone.

Comment: Is there any other way (other than view->bitmap->storage/contentprovider) to convert the current view in the app and share it with other apps?

Comment: @Rishi: Not really. You could use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+ for the screenshot part.

Comment: thanks for your responses for all my questions,
I am facing issue in sharing the in-memory image using fileProvider, the permissions are always asked by the receiving app, can you please comment?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615290/sharing-bitmap-in-memory-without-asking-for-read-permissions-using-action-send