# Sharing bitmap in memory without asking for read permissions using ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am trying to store a bitmap within the app's storage using file provider and then share it via ACTION_SHARE,
I am trying to avoid the read external storage permissions while sharing the image (it is the screenshot of the current view of the app -> bitmap).

Though I add the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION flag the receiver app always asks for the permissions, if I grant the permissions then the image is accessible by the receiver app else the receiver app does not show the image.

Can someone explain what the issue could be?

Should I create a custom ContentProvider instead of using FileProvider?

Here is my code:

```
Manifest:
<application>
...
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.user.samplescreenshotapp.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>


xml/filepaths:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

Code which triggers the share:

```
    File imagePath = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
    File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.user.samplescreenshotapp.fileprovider", newFile);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, contentUri);

    shareIntent.setData(contentUri); //Tried with and without this

    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); //Tried with setFlag also


    //shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sharing..");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");

    startActivity(shareIntent); //Also tried startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

Comment: "the receiver app always asks for the permissions" -- what does this mean? "if I grant the permissions" -- what does this mean?

Comment: `the receiver app`. Which app exactly? How many apps did you try?

Comment: "The receiver app always asks for permissions", when I try to share via an app (I tried just with twitter share and google drive ), they ask permissions for every trial I performed (I have mentioned what all options I tried in the comments abobe).

Comment: The receiver app: twitter and google drive, they asked for read permissions, Facebook was not even able to pull the image (it just showed the extra_text did not even ask for permissions for accessin image  ).

Comment: Can you try a normal email app?

Comment: Gmail worked, but it works always even without read flag. But how do I get it working for all the apps?

Comment: "If I grant the permissions" means when I click on a network like say twitter then twitter asks for read permissions, I granted it!

Comment: ?? ping. Any comments?

Comment: I tried couple of apps, only Gmail app, Pinterest app and hangouts app were able to pull the image without asking for read permissions. Rest other apps like twitter, FB, Google drive, etc are asking for read permissoins.

Comment: @greenapps, is there a specific reason to try on normal email app?